# Is there a way to convert a powershell string into a hashtable?

Tags: powershell

Is there is any way to tell powershell to construct a hashtable from a string that's formatted using the normal syntax for creating hashtables inline?

For example, is there any way to do something like:

```
$fooHashString = "@{key='value'}
$fooHash = TellPowershellToEvaluateSpecialStringExpressions($fooHashString)
$fooHash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key                            value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, shortly after posting this I stumbled upon the answer. I just needed to use the "Invoke-Expression" command on the string.

```
$fooHashString = "@{key='value'}"
$fooHash = Invoke-Expression $fooHashString
$fooHash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key                            value
```

Comment: First line of your code is missing a closing double quote

Comment: @taclight better now?

Comment: My answer, which was downvoted, is better than this. There are security concerns with `Invoke-Expression` as it could lead to unintended code execution or script injection.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of reasons why using Invoke-Expression is considered a code smell. See the following blog posts for details of this

- [PowerShell Code Smell: Invoke-Expression (and some suggestions)](https://powershellstation.com/2015/12/09/code-smell-invoke-expression/)
- [Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

If you are using PowerShell version 3.0 or above an alternative approach is to use the ConvertFrom-StringData. You can find details on how to use this on the MSDN page [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata)

In your case, you could use the following to create the HashTable

```
$HashString = "key1=value1 `n key2=value2"
ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $HashString
```

Alternatively, you could generate the content within a here string like this

```
$HashString = @'
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
'@
ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $HashString
```

Unfortunately, this won't work if you include `\` within the string because the `ConvertFrom-StringData` CmdLet sees it as an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better answer is here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2vqxpu/hashtable_string_to_hashtable_object/cokcfmq/

You would want to use `ScriptBlock`

Answer (score 0):

```
$fooHashString = "@{key='value'}" 
$fooHashString -replace '@{' -replace '}' -replace ';',"`n" -replace "'" |
  ConvertFrom-StringData

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key                            value
```

Comment: It is an alternative way to @gerard answer. It keeps the @{} syntax as origin string but it does not take all cases into account like $fooHashString = @{ key='value'; key2=@('valueA', 'valueB') }"